# Have a Crystal Reports formula convert numeric strings to values, but leave non-numeric blank/null

Tags: crystal-reports, null, formula

I have a string field that mostly contains numeric decimal values, but sometimes contains values like "<0.10" or "HEMOLYSIS".

I want to use a formula to convert these numeric value strings to values, leaving non-values blank (null).

```
if isNumeric({a_omgang.omg_resultat}) then
    toNumber({a_omgang.omg_resultat})
```

returns 0 for all non-numeric values, which makes it hard to calculate e.g. average or mean, or to count the number of values. (The latter can of course be achieved by using a running total count with `isNumeric` evaluation formula.)

Any suggestions how I can get the formula to work as I want?

Edit: I want the value to be blank (null), not just turn of visibility if non-numeric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the past, I've created a SQL Expression that returns a NULL:

```
-- {@DB_NULL}
-- Oracle syntax
(
SELECT NULL FROM DUAL
)
```

```
-- {@DB_NULL}
-- MS SQL syntax
(
SELECT NULL
)
```

Then I reference this field in the formula:

```
// {@FormulaField}
If IsNumberic({table.field} Then
  ToNumber({table.field})
Else
  ToNumber({@DB_NULL})
```

Comment: Interesting concept, but I get "Invalid object name 'DUAL'" when I run against MS SQL server. Have tried to change it to actual table names, but still get errors.

Comment: Try just `SELECT NULL`.  I don't have access to SQL Server, so I can't test this.

Answer (score 2):

You can get this to work by doing the following:

1. Create a new formula and just enter a number into it, then save. Crystal will now associate this formula with a numeric return value.
2. Go back into the formula and **delete the number** and resave it. Now you have a formula that returns a null, but CR has already associated it as being a numeric formula so you can now use it anywhere you could use a numeric type.

```
if isNumeric({a_omgang.omg_resultat}) 
  then toNumber({a_omgang.omg_resultat})
else {@NullNumeric}
```

Note that you can also use this for any other data types (including strings since an empty string is not equivalent to a null string) and it is extremely useful for using with summary functions where you just want to straight-up ignore certain rows.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it is *a* solution.

Create a running total formula for the maximum of the field. Evaluate by formula
`NumericText(Replace({a_omgang.omg_resultat}, ".", ","))`
and reset by formula
`true`

This will give you the maximum result of every entry. (I.e. that entry.) Only entries that can be converted to a value will be evaluated, so all others will be null. Having `true` as resetting formula makes sure that you always get the value of the entry being evaluated.

The result of this running total can then be converted to a value using the formula in the question.

The `Replace()` is due to locale and may not be needed depending on your system settings. If needed, it will also have to be used in the value converting formula.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge you can't do this directly. If a numeric formula field returns a null it is converted to 0.

You say you can't suppress. Could you convert to a number then back to a string?

Comment: For this specific report it would suffice to suppress, but I'm interested in a general solution. Updating question.