# how to get a blank date in Crystal report instead of 12/30/1899

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, crystal-reports

I am using crystal report and i an using a date parameter. In some cases i am not returning any date from database. The system is tracking a default date 12/30/1899. So in this case i want to bind the report with blank date. Need to show all other fields with blank date. Pls do an help for this

Thanks in advance
Jidheesh

Comment: Try my answer to question [Have a Crystal Reports formula convert numeric strings to values, but leave non-numeric blank/null][1].

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858187/have-a-crystal-reports-formula-convert-numeric-strings-to-values-but-leave-non

Answer (score 2):

use this format in select query

```
select isnull(dateColumn,''),column2 from table
```

Comment: Or to make it non-Microsoft-proprietary: `select coalesce(dateColumn,''), column2 from table`

Answer (score 0):

In the field added to the report, go to "Format Object" and check the "suppress" checkbox, then add this formula by clicking on the bottom at the right of that chackbox:

```
{DATE_FIELD} = Date (1899,12,30)
```

Where DATE_FIELD is the field of your object.

This will suppress the field when the date is equals to 1899/12/30.